# mySQL and monoDevelop configuration issue

Tags: mysql, monodevelop

I set up a connection on mono to mySQL and it worked for the page I was working on but not any of the other pages in my project.

Also, when I came back to the project another time. The name of the connection was saved but it was not associated with the same page so my updates didn't register via the localhost/test link used previously. Does anyone have an idea why this might be?

am running it on linux Lubuntu if that makes anything clearer.